How to create new table from existing table, where column A in another column
I have a dataset of orders, and a second list of order ID's for which there were problems. I would like to create a new table consisting of all of the values from the original set, where Column A (Order ID) is in Sheet 2 Column A (Order ID).
I've tried various things with Pivot Tables, Conditional Formatting, VLOOKUP and XMATCH, but have not been able to get it to work. I'm tempted to dump it into a database so that I can just run the super simple SQL query ("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column1 FROM Table2)") to get this, but I'd like to know how to accomplish this in Excel.

Try merging tables in Power Query with an INNER JOIN on Order ID.

If you want them in tables power query is the way to do so. Filter will create a spill range, but excel doesn't play nicely with objects & spill ranges yet.

pls. try this formula in cell I1 and drag down
=CHOOSEROWS($A$1:$E$19,TOROW(IF(H1=$A$1:$A$19,ROW($A$1:$A$19),1/0),2))
Column H is the column of the list of the values to search
Column A:E are the data range
Column I is the result column

